# Tor Browser location confusion

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Using Tor Browser, three links showing from onion dropdown were all listed in France but mail client logged into from that tab says the incoming connection is from RU so wondering how that can be?  If there's a similar question/answer I missed pls point me in the right direction ;-) Tx

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options:

1. Out dated GeoIP information, potentially both your local GeoIP database and the sites disagree about the supposed location of the IP address.
2. The onion menu shows the information about the relay in question, which shows where the connection goes *in* to the relay, where it comes *out* can be somewhere else entirely.